# Paragraph between hyperlink and Image URL has been cut off using Image hyperlink pattern

Tags: .net, regex

I have a paragraph that looks like this:

```
First.Check out this <a href="https://sample.com/applications/Documents/SolutionContingency.html" target="_blank">demo </a>to learn about the Solution Contingency feature of MME.  

Second Paragraph. Get your head out of the fog and use the solution contingency feature in MME! All the costs for a WMU are displayed on the Costs screen in the Forecast menu. 

<a href="https://blog.sample.com/mme/files/2013/07/SC2.jpg"><img title="SC2" alt="" src="https://blog.sample.com/mme/files/2013/07/SC2.jpg" width="1262" height="711" /></a>

Fourth.You should review your solution contingency at least once a month.
```

I just Replaced the image url using regex with empty string using this:

```
(<a.*?<img.*?>.*?/a>|<img.*?>)
```

Do you have any idea why the output was cut off from the hyperlink upto the picture. It only displays first and fourth paragraph.

Here's the output:

```
First.Check out this Fourth.You should review your solution contingency at least once a month.
```

Removing of pictures works fine when the paragraph has no hyperlink..

Comment: Haven't you just asked this but in a different way a few minutes ago !!.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after.  If you want to just isolate the image tags, you can change your regex to the following: `(<img.*?>)`